# reading a variable with datatype str to sending it to .sendkeys in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I am trying to take an input from user,encrypt it and save it to a txt file/binary file read it back decrypt it and use it fill .sendkeys(variable) but it doesn't seem to work i also tried searching it online and with other posts here but nothing worked for me
The string i am inputting from my user is str
then i write to a txt file(binary in the example below)
then read it back again decrypt it and the datatype here is  which i assume is str

```
from selenium import webdriver
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)

def load_key():
    return open("key.key", "rb").read()
    
def encrypt_write(data,file):
    data = bytes(data ,'utf-8')
    key = load_key()
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypteddata = f.encrypt(data)
    f = open(file,"wb")
    f.write(encrypteddata)
    print(encrypteddata)
    f.close()
    
def read_decrypt(file):
    f = open(file,"rb")
    data = f.readline()
    f.close()
    key = load_key()
    f = Fernet(key)
    decrypted_encrypted = f.decrypt(data)
    decrypted_encrypted = str(decrypted_encrypted)[2:-1] 
    return decrypted_encrypted
    
email = input("email:")
write_key()
encrypt_write(email, 'efile.bin')
remail = read_decrypt('efile.bin')
print(type(remail))
print(remail)
driver = Edge(executable_path='msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
try:
        email = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email')))
        print ("Page is ready!")
        email.send_keys(remail)
        print('Login sucessful')
except TimeoutException:
            print ("Error logining in")
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.quit()
```

Here write_key() and load_key are dedicated to encrypting data using cryptography.fernet  encrypt_write fuction takes the data encrypts it and writes it in a binary file and read_decrypt fuction reads the binary file decrypts it and returns the string.
email is the input email variable
remail is the email read from the binary file
" i have also used print statements to get a better understanding and i am using edge browser"

my output is

```
email:user@xyz
b'gAAAAABfW8uWCwiCUyUMJAcYqmICv5cBAD9SmMGx6rSQMunwE12W9MKidKq8z2QsZx4yNIYM0jFW-kx3BcNe8KSRrHl_TU2_Yw=='
<class 'str'>
user@xyz
Page is ready!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-79206622bda1> in <module>
     47         email = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email')))
     48         print ("Page is ready!")
---> 49         email.send_keys(email)
     50         print('Login sucessful')
     51 except TimeoutException:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    476 
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
--> 478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py in keys_to_typing(value)
    148                 typing.append(val[i])
    149         else:
--> 150             for i in range(len(val)):
    151                 typing.append(val[i])
    152     return typing
```

i also tried `email.send_keys(str(remail))`
which gave fill the entry box email as `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="144eff9ac68a56f6b5a78b4b6ccde663", element="b2ed690c-0410-4838-a4ea-67edd3dfaf18")>`
i also tried `remail = str(remail)`
which didn't do anything

Comment: Produce a minimal example.

Comment: Also len() is only for array size maybe you want the length of the string?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: show minimal working code which we could run and see problem and test solutions.